# (Reopened) Does this question really not have a goal that can be addressed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question was closed for supposedly not having a goal we can address: [How to find motivation to keep applying to jobs after being rejected](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/181900/how-to-find-motivation-to-keep-applying-to-jobs-after-being-rejected)

I strongly disagree with both the closure and the stated reason; "how do I prevent myself from getting discouraged by rejection when I'm looking for jobs?" is an *exceedingly* common problem (and a goal that *can* be addressed).

Can this be re-opened?

Comment: I agree, reopened

Comment: Good catch! I agree

Comment: *"I'm voting to close this question because finding motivation and setting goals seems more about psychology than the workplace. Although I think there is potentially a good question or two that can spin off from this one, like 'How much time should I spend per job application?' or even 'How can I best approach a job search?' (which is quite broad, but might be okay). ..."* - at least that's the reason I gave for voting to close. I also said *"The best goals are ones that work best for you personally"*, which makes a large part of the question hard to answer in any useful way.

Comment: I feel [the top-voted answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/181901/8234) has some good advice, but it's not actually directly answering the question that was asked at all. That is kind of okay from an answerer's perspective, since the question that was asked is not on topic at all, and what it was answering is probably the closest on-topic question, but it does just highlight that the question isn't on topic and should be closed or edited, or new questions should be derived from that one (and all 3 of those options are things this community is way too averse to).

Comment: @BernhardBarker How are goal-setting and finding motivation *not* workplace issues? Those seem like classic challenges that people routinely face in their jobs. I don't think that the fact that it's also about psychology changes the fact that this is a very common workplace issue.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Goal-setting (possibly excluding things like OKRs) and finding motivation are workplace-related, but they're outside of the expertise one would expect a workplace expert to have (much like fixing an issue with your computer can be workplace-related, but it still doesn't belong here). Pursuing inappropriate goals can cause psychological harm and motivation issues relates to depression and burnout. As a workplace expert, one arguably wouldn't necessarily know much about that, while a psychologist or productivity expert should know a whole lot about that.